# Examples of other hierarchy problems

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model, fine-tuning

The commonly quoted version of the hierarchy problem (at least, the one that I have heard), is concerned with the surprisingly low mass of the Higgs. We would expect the Higgs mass squared to have quantum corrections of order $\sim \Lambda^2$ where $\Lambda$ is the cut-off scale, unless there are delicate cancellations between terms to very high precision. This seems unlikely to happen without reason, and proposed solutions like supersymmetry and composite Higgs are used to explain why the Higgs can have a low mass.

Although it seems likely that there should be some underlying cause, do we have more concrete reasons to believe so, other than our desire for an aesthetic solution? Specifically, I would like to know if there have been other similar problems, where something that could have been an improbable coincidence was discovered to be because of new physics. Is there a precedent for other hierarchy problems, where some quantity was vastly different from the expected value, but could potentially be explained as a consequence of delicate cancellations, but ultimately led to fundamental advances in the theory which explained it completely?

Comment: the mass of the electron as a zero sized elementary particle. the calculated mass from its self energy is infinite. even if a small size is assumed, the calculated mass is much higher than the observed mass. Renormalization methods in the past involved other mass component for the electron that cancelled the infinite mass except for the small amount of observed mass. The current theories to solve this are based on vacuum polarization of virtual particle pairs, within the quantum uncertainty range.